# how to get changing captchas from html using python

Tags: python

I have been trying to get a text from a HTML file using strip() but it was not useful for me any idea how to get a text from a long html page using python?

ex:

```
import urllib.request
import sys
with urllib.request.urlopen('http://ctf.slothparadise.com/walled_garden.php?name=BMX') as response:
    html= response.read()
    html = str(html)
```

and I need to get the captchas to complete the challenge and get the KEY please help :D thanks

Comment: Instead of trying to do the parsing yourself, maybe use a web scraping library like [Beautiful Soup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) that's been written for this kind of thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a HTML Parser, for python i highly recommend [Beautiful Soup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) ,

> Beautiful Soup is a Python library for pulling data out of HTML and
>   XML files. It works with your favorite parser to provide idiomatic
>   ways of navigating, searching, and modifying the parse tree. It
>   commonly saves programmers hours or days of work.

Installation :

```
pip install bs4
```

Usage :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_string = "<html><head><title>This is a title</title></head><body></body></html>"
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_string, 'html.parser')
print soup.title # => "This is a title"
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using BeautifulSoup, as mentioned above. However, if you want a quick fix solution, then just use regex to find the captcha.

```
import urllib.request
import sys
import re
with urllib.request.urlopen('http://ctf.slothparadise.com/walled_garden.php?
name=BMX') as response:
    html= response.read()
    html = str(html)
    #get the captcha
    print(re.findall(r'<pre>(.*?)</pre>', html))
```

Comment: thank you :D , but can u please tell me what is this line do ?     "re.findall(r'<pre>(.*?)</pre>', html)"

Comment: It's a regular expression to find all the elements inside <pre> tag. I examined the html structure and found that there's only single such tag. Hence such a quick fix, dirty solution is feasible. In general case, you'll be better off using BeautifulSoup